# Can I use mod_rewrite and apache custom error handling together?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, error-handling

We are currently on a load balanced environment and we are having an issue with one of our servers. We are getting an error 500 due to an application crash. As we have our techs look into this I wanted to make a fix. I would like a way to redirect to the same page on the second server when you receive an error 500.

In apache you can simply redirect using this method:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://xxx/
```

My question is, is it possible to have mod_rewrite point the redirect to the specific page that the error 500 came from?

For example, vm1.foo.bar/contact has a error 500 so we need to redirect it to vm2.foo.bar/contact

Also, this is a Windows Server running apache.

Comment: Not in .htaccess but inside your 500 handler you can do that.

Comment: Can you give me an article or example on how this is done?

Comment: ok check updated code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok posting some command as per comments above.

First define `ErrorDocument` like this:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /handle500.php
```

Then inside `/handle500.php` have code like this:

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == 'vm1.foo.bar')
      header ("Location: http://vm2.foo.bar" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   else
      header ("Location: http://vm1.foo.bar" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   exit;
?>
```

Comment: Seriously, You are the best!